# Как создать вторую форму в Lazarus?

Tags: lazarus

Я создала несколько форм. В первой форме я показала вторую (Unit2.Form2.Show). Проблема в том, что я её просто показала и не могу взаимодействовать с её компонентами. Мне нужно при помощи второй формы открыть третью. ShowModal по каким-то причинам не работает. Не знаю, что делать (._.)/

```
begin 
  if pos(fPassword.Text, b.Text) > 0 then 
  begin 
    Main.Form2.Show; 
    Form1.Hide; 
  end 
  else 
    ShowMessage ('Ooops! Wrong password or password''s field is empty. Try again.'); 
  b.Free; 
end;
```

Comment: "ShowModal ... не работает." - у всех работает, а у Вас не работает? Вы считаетe, что кода `Unit2.Form2.Show` достаточно для ответа на Ваш вопрос?

Comment: Я не поняла, что Вы имеете ввиду. ShowModal не работает в том плане, что на форме, показанной при помощи ShowModal, не работают компоненты. Unit2.Form2.Show мне не помогает, поэтому я и спросила здесь. Если Вы не можете или не хотите мне помочь, пожалуйста, пройдите мимо.

Comment: Смысл фразы "не работают компоненты" известен только Вам. Я, конечно, могу пройти мимо, но кто тогда Вам объяснит, как плохо Вы задали вопрос?

Comment: "не работают" - это значит не работают. Например, компонент Button1 не открывает третью форму. А компонент Image вообще не показывается на второй форме, хотя Visible := True.

Comment: Мы продвигаемся вперед семимильными шагами :)! Вы уже приоткрыли завесу тайны, скрывающую Ваш код. Еще немного, и Вы полностью поймете, что мы не видим Ваш экран с кодом и мысли в Вашем мозгу.

Comment: Если Вы не знали решение проблемы без кода, то стоило сразу попросить его скинуть или сказать об этом, вместо того, чтобы ходить вокруг да около. Вот кусочек кода:
begin
     if pos(fPassword.Text, b.Text) > 0 then
     begin
       Main.Form2.Show;
       Form1.Hide;
     end
     else
     ShowMessage ('Ooops! Wrong password or password''s field is empty. Try again.');
     b.Free;
   end;

Comment: Большое спасибо за Ваше замечание. Я обязательно учту это в будущем.

Comment: На второй форме расположена только кнопка, которая должна открывать третью форму при помощи команды Form.Show. Но, кнопка не работает.

Comment: Что такое `b` в приведенном коде? *(намекаю - кода мало)*

Comment: Вам не нужна эта переменная. Лучше ответьте мне (если только для этого Вам не потребуется код), при открытии второй формы командой Form2.Show, расположенные на Form2, компоненты должны работать или нет?

Comment: Отвечаю: компоненты должны работать. Могу опубликовать слово "должны" в качестве ответа, если Вы примете его как правильный.

Comment: Спасибо. Я просто пересоздала программу, и всё заработало.